# How to generate random match-up using round robin system?

Tags: mysql, sql

given these table **Players**

```
| id |   name   |
+----+----------+
| 1  |  tawing  |
| 2  |  master  |
| 3  |  pepe    |
| 4  |  bethel  |
| 5  |  richard |
```

**matches**:
tawing vs master
master vs pepe
master vs bethel
master vs richard....

Here's what I've tried so far

```
select t1.id
       , t1.name 
from Players t1 
cross apply Players t2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for:

```
select concat(t1.name ,' vs ',  t2.name) "Match-up"
from players t1 
cross join players t2
where t1.name <> t2.name;
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=60e88baa524c975c9f71db2596d5da7b)